# How to run Scala on Windows Phone?

Tags: .net, scala, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have found a tutorial how to run Scala on .NET: http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2009/01/getting-started-with-scala-on-net.html

Is it possible to run Scala on Windows Phone? Any hints how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information I can glean from that page, it seems possible but it's going to be some work and the development experience won't be brilliant.

I'd recommend creating a C# WP7 application and creating your views in there.

Next, compile your Scala while referencing the `2.0.5.0` version of `mscorlib` and the other assemblies.

You should the be able to reference the Scala-compiled assembly from your WP7 application and therefore utilise any domain/view model classes in there.

Answer (score 1):

The latest how-to on Scala.NET (June 2011) is

http://lamp.epfl.ch/~magarcia/ScalaNET/2011Q2/PreviewScalaNET.pdf

Comment: Precompiled versions of the Scala library and the compiler for .NET can be obtained via SVN, in the bin folder of the preview:
svn co http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/svn-repos/scala/scala-experimental/trunk/bootstrap